# Image not received, sent via mms using VBA, Twilio and Microsoft ACCESS

Tags: vba, twilio, ms-access-2016

I need to send a image from my pc in a text message using Twilio and Microsoft Access.

I was able to successfully send a text message via Microsoft Access. However, the image wasn't sent.  I found a parameter called "mediaURL".  I am trying to have mediaURL refer to a image on my pc ("d:\imagefolder").

Has anyone been able to do this.  Here is my code to send the text message.

```
Dim MessageUrl As String
    Dim FromURLEncode As String
    Dim ToURLEncode As String
    Dim imageURL As String

    On Error GoTo Error_Handler

    ' setup the URL
    MessageUrl = BASEURL & "/2010-04-01/Accounts/" & ACCOUNTSID & "/Messages"
    imageURL = "d:\imagefolder\mypicture.png"

    ' setup the request and authorization
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    http.Open "POST", MessageUrl, False, ACCOUNTSID, AUTHTOKEN
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

    Dim postData As String
    postData = "From=" & fromNumber _
                & "&To=" & toNumber _
                & "&Body=" & body _
                & "&MediaURL=" & imageURL

    Debug.Print postData

    ' send the POST data
    http.send postData

    ' optionally write out the response if you need to check if it worked
    Debug.Print http.responseText

    If http.Status = 201 Then

    ElseIf http.Status = 400 Then
        MsgBox "Failed with error# " & _
            http.Status & _
            " " & http.statusText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            http.responseText
    ElseIf http.Status = 401 Then
        MsgBox "Failed with error# " & http.Status & _
            " " & http.statusText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed with error# " & http.Status & _
            " " & http.statusText
    End If

Exit_Procedure:

    On Error Resume Next

    ' clean up
    Set http = Nothing

Exit Function

Error_Handler:

    Select Case Err.Number

        Case NOINTERNETAVAILABLE
            MsgBox "Connection to the internet cannot be made or " & _
                "Twilio website address is wrong"

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & "; Description: " & Err.Description

            Resume Exit_Procedure

        Resume

    End Select
```

Comment: I don't know twilio, but I do a guess seeing your code : Maybe you can't send a local image using their MediaURL argument, because it only accept an online image ( `htttp://anything.com/anyimage.jpg` ). Maybe you could make a test with an online image instead and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to send text messages with images by using MediaUrl.  My Code was using MediaURL.  It has to be exactly "MediaUrl".  Once, I figured that out, I have been able to send text messages with images.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As Thomas G answered in a comment, your problem is that the image is on your computer. The URL needs to be available to Twilio.

You will need to upload the image to a server, either your own or a public service, and then using the for that server.

Check out [the documentation on sending MMS with Twilio for more details](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

Comment: I tried using  OneDrive and get a link and that didn't work.  I tried DropBox and got URL from that.  I am going through the documentation.  However, I do not see enough so far to understand the syntax for postdata with mediaURL.  I found a test on Twilio sight to send a text message and image and I received the text message and image.  It must have something to do with the syntax and the mediaURL parameter.

Comment: I have been spending several days going through the documentation.  From all accounts, my code is spot on.  I am using a public folder in DropBox.  I've checked my Twilio account programmable sms logs.  All text messages are showing as delivered.  However, only the text message is being received.  The image is never received.

Comment: I've been able to retrieve the SID after I've sent out a message.  It begins with SM* rather than MM*.  This confirms that the message is not going out as a mms, which is why I am not receiving the image.

Comment: Which country are you trying to send the MMS message to?

Comment: I am trying to send message to my phone...in the US.  It is approved through Twilio.  I used the website and received an image and text.  However, trying it with the code I found in the article is not working.      I just get the text.

Comment: I notice you're not URL encoding the `imageURL` in your code. Have you tried that?

Comment: Code currently trying to use.

' setup the URL
 MessageUrl = BASEURL & "/2010-04-01/Accounts/" & ACCOUNTSID & "/Messages"
   ' imageURL = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29189302/SharedImage/Churchtomorrow.jpeg"

Comment: That `imageURL` gives a 404 for me.

Comment: I think when I copied the URL, it added some characters.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29189302/SharedImage/Churchtomorrow.jpeg

This should work fine.

Thanks.